# Python's M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher not working with C++ encrypted data

Tags: c++, python, openssl, aes, python-2.7

I have some data that was encrypted using OpenSSL in C++ using aes_256_cbc and I need to decrypt it in Python.  I figured using M2Crypto, being a wrapper for OpenSSL should make this easy but I'm not getting the same data out.

I've read the [`test_AES` code](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_evp.py) and it hasn't helped.  I'm getting data out, it's just not the right data.

```
c = Cipher(alg='aes_256_cbc', key=binaryKey, iv=iv, op=0, d='sha256', i=5, salt=knownSalt, padding=0)
v = c.update(binaryDataToDecrypt)
v += c.final()
```

At this point, afaik, v should be my data and it isn't...  I found another [Q here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830835/m2crypto-aes-256-cbc-not-working-against-encoded-openssl-files) where it was mentioned that the first 16 bytes of the data to decrypt are the salt so I also tried the following with no luck:

```
c = Cipher(alg='aes_256_cbc', key=binaryKey, iv=iv, op=0, d='sha256', i=5, salt=binaryDataToDecrypt[0:16], padding=0)
v = c.update(binaryDataToDecrypt[16:])
v += c.final()
```

Comment: There is no salt in AES/CBC. Though it could be that it is used with a password (and hash function/iteration count) to derive the key ... no idea about OpenSSL/M2Crypto, though. Showing the code used to encrypt could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question I linked that mentioned slicing off the first 16 bytes may have been targeted to a different implementation.  It turns out I had to slice off the final 16 bytes.  You also have to make sure you're slicing those 16 bytes off after you've converted the data into binary format so that it really is 16 **bytes**

Also, as mentioned in the comments by Paulo, AES doesn't use salt so that parameter should be left to whatever the default is.